# How to install SFML Thor extension MacOSX?

Tags: c++, macos, sfml

I am in development study and I have to develop a game in C ++ with the SFML library.

I am new in c++. I already have created a project and installed SFML on my mac also in my project. Everything is OK but I want to implement Thor extension (http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/) and after many, many, many research on the Internet I despair and asks if anyone knows how to install Thor on Mac and implement it in my project... ?

Thank you for any help.

PS : Sorry for my English...

Comment: Step 1) download Thor source. Step 2) compile and install Thor. Step 3) include Thor in your project. Step 4) remember to ship Thor as part of your application.  See also the [installation tutorial](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/tutorials/v2.1/installation.html)

Comment: Yess ! I have arrived! thank you very much :)